# 'Charss' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

i am new on django and i have this problem in the title 
'Charss' object has no attribute 'get'
this is my code

```
class Charss(View):
def __init__(self,data):
    self.data = models.Chars.objects.using('Chars').filter(del_field = 0)
def ppop(request,self):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    result = sock.connect_ex(('127.0.0.1',1433))
    if result  == 0:
        msg = 'ON'
        return render(request, 'CharsAccount.html',{'msg':msg})
    else:
        msg ='OFF'
        return render(request, 'CharsAccount.html',{'msg':msg})
def CharsAccount(request,self):
    return render(request, 'CharsAccount.html',{'data':self.data})
```

sorry for my bad english

Comment: You need to add a method named `get` to the view to handle GET requests

Comment: sorry i am new but where i can add get ?